# PDFBox split multithread range page of single PDF

Tags: java, multithreading, pdf, pdfbox, runnable

I have a problem with the PDFBox library, I have a single pdf and I have to split it into n files, I need to be very fast in this operation because the pdf is very large. So I used a parallel approach. I managed to split all the pages through the use of PageExtractor, but I noticed that in some cases (not always) the images are not viewable. this is my code :

```
        Long endBu = sommario.getEndDoc();
        Long starBd = sommario.getStartBd();
        // range di pagine da estrarre per la bolletta unica
        PageExtractor pExBu = new PageExtractor(currentPdf);
        pExBu.setStartPage(startBu.intValue());
        pExBu.setEndPage(endBu.intValue());
        PDDocument pdfDocBu = null;
        try {
        
            pdfDocBu = pExBu.extract();
            String fileName = tempDirSplitter + nomeFileBolletta + "_" + TIPO_BOLLETTA.get(INDEX_BS_P_BD)
                    + Constants.PDF_EXTENSION;
         pdfDocBu.save(fileName);
                } finally {
            try {
                if (null != pdfDocBu) {

                    pdfDocBu.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                getLogger().error("Errore Chiusura Pdf "+item.getIdDocumento() +  " - " + pdfDocBu.getNumberOfPages());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

this piece of code is in a class of type runnable

Comment: Does this problem only occur when you run it in parallel? Or does it also occur when you run it in a single thread? Asking because you're not showing any "parallel" in the code that you posted, and if it is only a problem when you run it in parallel, then the problem is likely in that part of your code (that you haven't posted).

Comment: there might be problems if the single pages are using common resources and you are closing pdfDocBu.